# Can we put tab bar on top>?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

Say I like tab bar style button and I want to put it somewhere on the screen.

Can I do that?

This the the documentation for tabbar

```
Provides a mechanism for displaying a tab bar at the bottom of the screen and supports the display and selection of tab bar items (instances of UITabBarItem). You can use UITabBarDelegate to specify custom views for tab bar items.
```

Comment: Why dont you use a toolbar instead? Tab bar is supposed to be at the bottom of the view and Apple gives priority to consistency across applications(You can see that mentioned in HIG). So it would be better to tweak your design a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can put it at the top, but it's probably against the HIG. However, I don't understand the intent of your question -- you obviously tried putting it at the top, so why ask a question to which you already know the answer?

Comment: I wonder if anything will go wrong if I put it on top. I noticed that I too can put nav bar anywhere. In fact, I can't put nav bar on the very top which is where it should be.

Answer (score 1):

No. By definition, tab bars go on the bottom of the screen -- the top is reserved for navigation bars.

Comment: And so why can I drag drop UITabBar all the way to the top?

Comment: There is no technical reason for a `UITabBar` to be in any specific location on the screen. I have an iPad app with a tab bar halfway up the screen. If used properly, there should be no problem. But no one can say for sure what the Apple review team will say.

Comment: rmaddy, would you turn this into an answer. And yes what does apple review team said?